# Probability proof clarification

Tags: probability

If A and A are two mutually exclusive events and $$P(B) > 0$$ show that$$P(A|A\cup B) = \frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)}$$

I thought that $$P(A|A\cup B)= \frac{P(A)\cap P(A\cup B)}{P(A\cup B)}$$ but apparently not.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(A)\cap P(A\cup B)$ does not make sense. It should be $P(A\cap (A\cup B))$. Then we have that
$$
P(A\mid A\cup B)
=\frac{P(A\cap (A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)}
=\frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)}
=\frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)}.
$$